# Dockerignore: Ignore everything except a folder

Tags: docker, docker-image

I want to ignore all the folders in `src/modules` except `mall` folder when build images. I try like below, but it doesn't work.

```
src/modules
!src/modules/mall
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate how it doesnt work? 

Files excluded when they should stay or files not excluded at all?

Answer (score 4):

Try using wildcards, and both for exclusions and inclusions in this case.

Also, .dockerignore supports ** wildcards for any number of directories depth like go does.

So try this:

```
src/modules/**
!src/modules/mall/**
```

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)

If this doesn't work, could you elaborate in what doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
src/modules/*
!src/modules/mall
```

Comment: What version of docker are you using?

Comment: docker verson: 1.12.6